# Can i seperate the URLs of back and front office of my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

i'm trying to use two different adresses for the back and front of my website.
ex :

www.somedomain.com/***
www.backsomedomaine.com/wp-amdin/***

i want to know if it possible to manage this action on Wordpress.

Comment: Yes, the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) would be a good candidate for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your main domain (www.somedomain.com) you can configure wp config to access the database normally. And you can block access to wp-admin folder or simply delete it.

Already at your www.backsomedomaine.com/wp-amdin/ you configure wp config with access to the same database and put an empty theme without displaying anything.

Note that you must configure wp config with your current url, ie each wp config with its respectful url.

define ('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com');
define ('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com');

another option is to use the wordpress api rest

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can get your informations in other database in an other link Wordpress or not with $.ajax, $.post, etc.

As it is WordPress, there are certainly tips to know, but before going further on the functioning of this CMS, we need to know if it is actually a single site that will search for data or there will be multiple URLs connecting to the database?